# What about the commitment phase questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

So there were [plenty of good questions there](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77518?phase=definition).

Would it be considered fair game to ask those on the main site now?

There could be some good questions there that *could* be left abandoned by the askers. I have a few there that I will re-ask. However I cannot ask a question where I have no level of expertise or affiliation with.

If there was a good painting question could someone that didn't ask it re-ask it on the main site? Assuming it was a well formed question of course.

Comment: Assuming that you actually have the same question yourself?

Answer (score 7):

I can't see why not, especially if you have the same question that they did.

If you don't, I recommend possibly giving the people who asked them initially the opportunity to do so first by waiting a few days at least, particularly if you have no subject knowledge yourself. We want to be certain to get a good base of users with some starting rep so I don't think we should make an effort to "force add" the questions from commitment phase, particularly as it can make whoever does it look a bit rep-hungry.

For example, if I think a question about woodcutting is really good but I have no actual interest in the subject, I will have difficulty actually formulating a good body to the question, so it doesn't make sense for me to ask the question myself.

However, if there's a question about crocheting that I've always had and I want to take the time to write a good question about it here, it completely makes sense for me to ask it, regardless of who asked it in commitment phase.

Comment: I whole agree with this. If the question in concept is good and you have the means to form a high quality question then go for it. Of course give the original ops a chance.

Comment: Key aspects to a good question are including enough details so it is answerable (and not too broad), and also being able to refine the question based on comments received. As long as the Question OP is able to do that, it's a valid question no matter who asks!